# How to install C standard library headers under Netbeans / Windows?

Tags: c, windows, netbeans, libraries, header-files

I want to be able to develop in C using the Netbeans IDE in my Windows environment, but can't figure out how to install the standard library headers for C on a Windows machine.

Google searches offered no success.

Tips?
Thanks.

Comment: cant you just copy them from another compiler/ide?

Comment: You don't have to 'install' the c library, there's always one there, otherwise your system just wouldn't work. Are you talking about the headers?

Answer (score 0):

If you want [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) support and are used to programming in a Linux environment, take a look at [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), [which uses](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.programming.glibc) the [newlib C library](http://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html). Otherwise you're probably looking for [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), which compiles against the [Microsoft C run-time library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Both Cygwin and MinGW provide their own set of headers for the standard C library.

Developing with Cygwin will require its libraries to be installed on client machines. However, you can build with the [mno-cygwin compiler flag](http://www.delorie.com/howto/cygwin/mno-cygwin-howto.html) to instead use the MinGW-32 headers and runtime libraries.

MinGW binaries should run on Windows clients without installing any extra libraries.